# Reload data - table empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 tables view . One is with category and the other with videos .I  added the favorite song into an array . But how can i reload my table with only the favorite videos when favorite category is selected ?

This is what i was trying but my table view is empty.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView.tag==0) {

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    cell.title.text=[[stories objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
   NSString * aux=[[stories objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"url"];
    NSString *   videoHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"100\" height=\"80\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",aux] ;


        NSString *imagine=[[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        cell.imageSong.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imagine];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagine]];
        cell.imageSong.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        cell.imageSong.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (!tableView.tag==0) {

        int row =indexPath.row;
        if (row==0) {
            self.title1.text=@"ALL SONGS";
            [stories removeAllObjects];
            [self parse];
            i=0;
            [self showMenu:nil];


        }

        else if (row==1) {

            self.title1.text=@"FAVORITE";
             b=[favoriteArray count];
            if (b==0) {
                NSLog(@"NSArray empty");
                [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Attention !" message:@"No videos !" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];


            }

            else{
                [stories removeAllObjects];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                i=0;
                [self showMenu:nil];
            }



        }
        else
        {
        self.title1.text=[categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        [stories removeAllObjects];
        NSString * path =[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
        i=0;
        [self showMenu:nil];}
        self.karaokeBTn.hidden=YES;
        self.menu.hidden=NO;
        self.title1.hidden=NO;
    }



-(void)parse{
    if ([stories count] == 0) {
        for (int i=0; i<[feeds count]; i++) {
            NSString * path =[feeds objectAtIndex:i];
            [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];

        }

    }
}
```

In favorite array i already have the url for video, title and image . i dont need to parse the feed again.

Comment: Yes. I have feeds.  when app starts the feed is parse , and i want to have the option "favorite song" . For this i dont need to parse again , because i already have the information needed in favoriteArray.

Comment: Great, I've just posted an answer. Check if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to reload your table after parsing:

```
-(void)parse{
    if ([stories count] == 0) {
        for (int i=0; i<[feeds count]; i++) {
            NSString * path =[feeds objectAtIndex:i];
            [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];

        }
        [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    }
```

Comment: i dont need to parse again , because i already have the objects for favoriteArray. I just want to dispayed in my tableView when , i select FAVORITE cell .

Comment: so two possibles in your case: 1. replace the story array with the entries of the favoriteArray. 2. your datasource change to the favoriteArray so 
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}` set a case for favourite and normal also with cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I understood your issue. But since you said your tableView is empty heres a possible solution.

How do you set `stories` array? If it's a asynchronous data fetch from web, you have a empty `stories` array when those delegate methods get called.

You have to reload table view once data fetching is done. On the completion block of your data fetching method.

`[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: when FAVORITE cell is selected i want to take items from favoriteArray to populate table view , not from stories array.